# How to Call PHP function outside

Tags: php, function

I'm learning PHP particularly about functions.. 
This question might looks silly but i want to know how below function will work..

```
function iterateArray($array)
{
  foreach($array as $item) {
    $newArray[] = 'Iterated: ' . $item;
}
return $newArray;
}
```

Here i tried to use the above function on my below code

```
$new = array('one', 'two', 'Three');
$myvar = iterateArray($new);

echo $myvar;
//echo $myvar[];
//echo $myvar[0];
```

These all effects as an error.. anyone can explain this..

Comment: error is : Array to string conversion error.. both are in same files only..

Comment: Yeah, you need to use `print_r($myvar);` Not `echo $myvar;`.

Comment: how do i echo it or print it..

Comment: As @Pupil's answer, the line where you have `echo $myvar;` should be changed to: `print_r($myvar);`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below :

```
<?php
function iterateArray($array)
{
    foreach($array as $item) {
        $newArray[] = 'Iterated: ' . $item;
    }
    return $newArray;
}



$new = array('one', 'two', 'Three');
$myvar = iterateArray($new);

print_r($myvar);
//echo $myvar[];

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Appreciate that you are putting efforts for learning.

You are returning `array()` from the function.

And `echo` function prints strings.

for `array()`, use `print_r()`

Other things are fine.

Another suggestion:

In the function body:

```
function iterateArray($array)
{
  $newArray = array(); // Declare it in case user passes blank array.
// Hence no loop and return statement will return undefined variable.
// To avoid this error, use above line.  
 foreach($array as $item) {
    $newArray[] = 'Iterated: ' . $item;
}
return $newArray;
}
```